# Applications of Gauss sums

Tags: number-theory

For proving the quadratic reciprocity, Gauss sums are very useful. However this seems an ad-hoc construction. Is this useful in a wider context? What are some other uses for Gauss sums?

Comment: [Related HSM.SE question](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/what-motivated-gauss-quadratic-sums)

Answer (score 35):

Gauss sums are not an ad-hoc construction!  I know two ways to motivate the definition, one of which requires that you know a little Galois theory and the other which is totally mysterious to me.

Here is the Galois-theoretic explanation.  Let $\zeta_p$ be a primitive $p^{th}$ root of unity, for $p$ prime.  The [cyclotomic field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field) $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ is [Galois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension), so one can define its [Galois group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_group), the group of all field automorphisms which preserve $\mathbb{Q}$.  Such an automorphism is determined by what it does to $\zeta_p$, and it must send $\zeta_p$ to another primitive $p^{th}$ root of unity.  It follows that the Galois group $G = \text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, which is cyclic of order $p-1$.

Now suppose $p$ is odd.  As a cyclic group of even order, $G$ has a unique subgroup $H$ of index two given precisely by the multiplicative group of quadratic residues $\bmod p$, so by the [fundamental theorem of Galois theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory) the fixed field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)^H$ is the unique quadratic subextension of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$.  And it's not hard to see that this unique quadratic subextension must be generated by

$$\sum_{\sigma \in H} \sigma(\zeta_p) = \sum_{a \text{ is a QR}} \zeta_p^a = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \zeta_p^{a^2} \right)$$

which you will of course recognize as a Gauss sum!  So the Gauss sum generates a quadratic subextension, and any of various methods will tell you that this subextension is precisely $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p^{\ast}})$ where $p^{\ast} = (-1)^{ \frac{p-1}{2} } p$.  (This does not actually require any computation: if you know enough algebraic number theory, it follows from a consideration of which primes ramify in cyclotomic extensions.)

The totally mysterious explanation is that Gauss sums naturally appear when you start thinking about the [discrete Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform).  For example, the trace of the DFT matrix is a Gauss sum.  But more mysteriously, Gauss sums are eigenfunctions of the DFT in a certain sense.  (I sketch how this works [here](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/some-quadratic-reciprocity/).)  There is a sort of mysterious connection here to the Gaussian distribution, which is an eigenfunction of the continuous Fourier transform; see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11053/whats-the-relationship-between-gauss-sums-and-the-normal-distribution).  Again, I don't know what to make of this.  There is a book by Berg called [The Fourier-analytic proof of quadratic reciprocity](http://books.google.com/books?id=fxVZybOHF8EC&pg=PR17&lpg=PR17&dq=fourier-theoretic+proof+of+quadratic+reciprocity&source=bl&ots=o4aiY9ferP&sig=Wj7JvvAdomtfCwy-UAFfgOKYPWs&hl=en&ei=ARntTKCBF6GShAf_6eTNDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBIQ6AEwAA) and it may or may not be about this construction.

Answer (score 13):

Not just **quadratic** reciprocity, one can use them to prove higher
reciprocity laws: see Ireland and Rosen's *A Classical Introduction
to Modern Number Theory*. They also turn up in the functional
equation for Dirichlet L-functions (and are massively generalized in the
topic of root numbers).

Answer (score 10):

It can be used to prove a certain theorem called the [Stickelberger's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stickelberger_theorem), the likes of which can in turn be used for proving things like [Catalan's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_conjecture).

Answer (score 9):

They are also used to describe something called the Talbot Effect:

http://www.phy.bris.ac.uk/people/berry_mv/research.html

look at #8 in the list. I attended a seminar by Mike Berry about 12 years ago where he claimed that the Talbot Effect was a physical manifestation of Gauss Sums.

Answer (score 7):

Gauss sums and exponential sums in general are particularly useful for determining the size of certain algebraic varieties in finite fields or even in general abelian groups.  If one defines

$$
A_t = \{x \in \mathbb{F}_q^d : f(x) = t\}
$$

where $t \in \mathbb{F}_q\setminus\{0\}$, then by orthogonality we have

$$
|A_t| = q^{-1} \sum_{s \in \mathbb{F}_q} \sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_q^d} \chi(s (f(x) - t)),
$$

where $\chi$ is any nontrivial additive character on $\mathbb{F}_q$.

For example, if one considers $x = (x_1, \dots , x_d) \in \mathbb{F}_q^d$ and defines $f(x) = x_1^2 + \dots + x_d^2$, then $A_t$ would be some finite field analogue of a sphere.  Bounding such a set would then be equivalent to bounding

$$
q^{-1}\sum_{s \in \mathbb{F}_q} \left(\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_q} \chi(sx^2) \right)^d \chi(-st).
$$

Gauss Sums and in particular well-known bounds for Gauss sums imply that such a sum is of size $q^{d-1}(1 + o_d(1))$ as $q \to \infty$.

As Qiaochu points out above, such bounds are nice to have when one works with the discrete Fourier transform.

Answer (score 6):

Srinivasa Ramanujan actually had discovered some definite integral formulas related to the Gauss sums. Please see the below article:

> - Some definite integrals connected with Gauss sums. *Messenger of Mathematics* XLIV, $1915$, $75-85$

From Wikipedia: ( Sorry, I can't explain this.)

> - The absolute value of *Gauss sums* is usually found as an application of Plancherel's theorem on finite groups.

Another application of the Gauss sum: [How to prove that: $\tan(3\pi/11) + 4\sin(2\pi/11) = \sqrt{11}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11246/how-to-prove-that-tan3-pi-11-4-sin2-pi-11-sqrt11/11288#11288)

> - http://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/luckyoct10.pdf

Answer (score 5):

A small additional note, in line with an earlier answer: Gauss sums are, literally, the Lagrange resolvents obtained in the course of expressing roots of unity in terms of radicals. (Yes, then the Kummer-Stickelberger business can be used to effectively obtain the actual radical expressions...:  [here](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/kummer_eis.pdf) .)