# What is the intuition behind Gauss sums?

Tags: number-theory, intuition, algebraic-number-theory

Let $ \chi $ be a character on the field $ F_p $, and fix some $a \in F_p $.
We define a Gauss sum to be:
$g_a (\chi) = \sum_{t\in F_p}\chi(t)\zeta^{at}$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $p^{th}$ root of unity.

What is the intuition behind this definition?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One explanation is given [in this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11675/applications-of-gauss-sums/11692#11692).  In the language of that answer, you want to describe the unique quadratic subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$.  Since it's quadratic, it's generated by the square root of some rational, so the Galois group acts by multiplication by $-1$ on it.  Therefore you want to find an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ such that the Galois group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\ast}$ acts by multiplication by $-1$ on it, and up to a constant that element is a Gauss sum (for the quadratic character).  Gauss sums with respect to more general characters have a similar relationship to actions of the Galois group.

Answer (score 21):

When you say $\chi$ is a character of the field $F_p$, you really mean it is a character of the group $F_p^\times$. Any (multiplicative) character $\chi$ on $F_p^\times$ can be extended to a function on $F_p$ by setting $\chi(0) = 0$, and with this convention $\chi$ as a function on $F_p$ is totally multiplicative. Fixing a choice of nontrivial $p$th root of unity $\zeta$, any function $f \colon F_p \rightarrow {\mathbf C}$ has a Fourier transform ${\mathcal F}f \colon F \rightarrow {\mathbf C}$ given by 
$({\mathcal F}f)(a) = \sum_{t \in F_p} f(t)\overline{\zeta^{at}}$.  So the Gauss sum  $g_a(\chi)$ is essentially the Fourier transform at $a$ of the function $\chi$ (as a function on $F$). For more on Fourier transforms of functions on a finite abelian group, see Section 4 (starting at Definition 4.4) of
https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/charthy.pdf

Another intuition (besides the idea that a Gauss sum of a character is basically the Fourier transform of that character, viewed as a function on the additive group $F_p$) is that a Gauss sum is a discrete analogue of the Gamma function. See pp. 56--58 of Koblitz's book "$p$-adic Analysis: A Short Course on Recent Work" for a table illustrating this analogy (including the idea that a Jacobi sum is like the Beta function).

Comment: Page 16, problem 7 I'm unable to find that excercise, can you update it please.

Comment: @S.SundaraNarasimhan the exercise isn't there, but the definition of Fourier transforms is (page 13).  Exercises for that section are on page 17 instead of 16 now.

Comment: Yes, I saw the definition and understood the point you were trying to make in the above answer. Also I must tell you that your notes are a very good source of learning new stuff, It is always a pleasure to read them ! Thank you very much for your efforts.

Answer (score 6):

They are the discrete Fourier transform of the character $\chi$ (which presumably is a *multiplicative* character -- like the quadratic symbol, no?). This allows one to express $\chi$ as a sum of exponentials.