# Why did people constructed Quadratic Gauss Sum?

Tags: number-theory, gauss-sums

I was studying number theory these days where Quadratic Gauss sum came up.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum

My question was that:

1. What motivated them to construct Gauss Sum in the first place.
2. Why did they use $(\frac{t}{p})l^{at}$ rather than simply say $(\frac{t}{p})l^{t}$ in the first place.

Comment: The Gauss sum is a special case of the Gauss sum of a Dirichlet character, which appears naturally in functional equations for L-functions. I don't know if this is where they were born. You may want to ask this at https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 1. A simple proof of the quadratic reciprocity theorem.

Comment: 2. The book by Ireland and Rosen on number theory has applications of Gauss sums almost everywhere.

Comment: @barto@DietrichBurde Thanks! The short answer was in the web barto given https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/what-motivated-gauss-quadratic-sums and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11675/applications-of-gauss-sums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One application of Gauss sums is finding intermediate fields between $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_n)$.

Here is a [link](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/332/30kummer.pdf) for more information.