# Is there an interpretation for this trigonometric identity?

Tags: trigonometry

A while ago I came across the following identity in an online math forum (of which I don't remember the name):
$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{11}\right)+4\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{11}\right)=\sqrt{11}.$$

It is not hard to give a proof by rewriting everything in terms of $\exp(i\pi/11)$ and applying a sequence of manipulations. I am wondering where this identity is coming from. Can somebody think of a geometric interpretation? Of an algebraic one?

Edit: Here's an example of what I mean by an algebraic interpretation: The identity $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{7}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{8}$$ expresses the fact that for the Chebyshev polynomial
$$T_7(x)=x(64x^6-112x^4+56x^2-7)$$
the product of the roots $\displaystyle \sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{7}\right)$, $1\leq k<7$, of the second factor is equal to the normalized constant term $\displaystyle \frac{7}{64}$.

Comment: You also have the similar but less interesting $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+4\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{3}\right)=\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: A proof of a similar identity can be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11246/how-to-prove-that-tan3-pi-11-4-sin2-pi-11-sqrt11. btw, what exactly do you mean by an algebraic Interpretation?

Comment: How do you get $\sqrt{11}$ on the RHS "by rewriting everything in terms of $\text{exp}(i\pi/11)$"?

Comment: @Américo: See [http://efreedom.com/Question/5-11246/Prove-Tan-Pi-11-Sin-Pi-11-Sqrt-11](http://efreedom.com/Question/5-11246/Prove-Tan-Pi-11-Sin-Pi-11-Sqrt-11)

Comment: Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 6):

I could only think of a direct trigonometric interpretation of the identity.

[image]

The radius of the circular sector is 1. The measures of the central angles and  the lengths of the line segments are:

1. The smaller angle: $\pi/11$ rad.
2. The bigger angle: $3\pi/11$ rad.
3. The red line segment: $\sqrt{11}$.
4. The vertical black line segment: $4\sin(3\pi/11)$.
5. The vertical light red segment: $\tan(3\pi/11)$.

The red line segment is the  hypotenuse of the right triangle  whose catheti are the line segment with length $\sqrt{10}$ and the orthogonal unit segment. The $\sqrt{10}$ line segment is the hypotenuse of the right triangle  whose catheti are the horizontal line segment with length 3 and the vertical line segment with length 1.

Edited: The angle $\pi/11=2\pi/22$ is not constructible with compass and straightedge (Wikipedia, [Constructible polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon) ). Therefore the figure is an [impossible construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_and_straightedge_constructions#Impossible_constructions) with compass and straightedge only.

Answer (score -4):

Remember the algebra form is $a+bi$.
You should calculate the first:
$|z| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$,
and then consider the angle "$\Phi$" (there are about 4 cases)...
I will give you a hint: Remember complex numbers, and the end is $z=|z|(\cos{\Phi}+i \sin{\Phi})$.

Comment: Did you read the question before posting your answer? I think @carinii states quite clearly that this computatonal approach is not the point of this question.