# On generalizing $\frac{17-\sqrt{17}}8 =\sin^2(t)+\sin^2(2t)+\sin^2(4t)+\sin^2(8t)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, galois-theory, radicals

Given $\color{blue}{t = 2\pi/p}$ for the appropriate prime $p=4m+1$.

**I. Sine**

$$\begin{align}
\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}8 &=\sin^2(t)\\ 
\frac{13+\sqrt{13}}8 &=\sin^2(t)+\sin^2(3t)+\sin^2(4t)\\
\frac{17+\sqrt{17}}8 &=\sin^2(3t)+\sin^2(5t)+\sin^2(6t)+\sin^2(7t)\\
\frac{29+\sqrt{29}}8 &=\sum_{k=1}^7\sin^2(a_k\, t)
\end{align}$$

with the seven $a_k = 1,4,5,6,7,9,13.$ And so on for other prime $p=4m+1.$ For the *opposite* sign, one uses the remaining integers $b_k \leq \frac{p-1}2.$ For example,

$$\frac{17-\sqrt{17}}8 =\sin^2(t)+\sin^2(2t)+\sin^2(4t)+\sin^2(8t)$$

where the $a_k$ are simply $2^n$. (The next Fermat prime $p=257$ isn't so nice since it has $256/4 = 64$ sine terms.)

---

**II. Cosine**

This uses *the same set* of multipliers $a_k$.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}8 &=\cos^2(t)\\ 
\frac{11-\sqrt{13}}8 &=\cos^2(t)+\cos^2(3t)+\cos^2(4t)\\
\frac{15-\sqrt{17}}8 &=\cos^2(3t)+\cos^2(5t)+\cos^2(6t)+\cos^2(7t)\\
\frac{27-\sqrt{29}}8 &=\sum_{k=1}^7\cos^2(a_k\, t)
\end{align}$$

with the same seven $a_k = 1,4,5,6,7,9,13.$ For the opposite sign,

$$\frac{15+\sqrt{17}}8 =\cos^2(t)+\cos^2(2t)+\cos^2(4t)+\cos^2(8t)$$

---

**III. Conclusion**

Given prime $p=4m+1$ and $t = 2\pi/p.$ The pattern clearly is,

$$\frac{p\pm\sqrt{p}}8 = \sum_{k=1}^m \sin^2(a_k\, t)$$

$$\frac{(p-2)\mp\sqrt{p}}8 = \sum_{k=1}^m \cos^2(a_k\, t)$$

**Question:** I used *Mathematica's* integer relations to find the above examples. But, for any prime $p=4m+1$, what is a clever and faster algorithm to derive the correct set of $a_k$?

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55120/) is clearly related, but didn't give a general algorithm for other prime $p$.

Comment: Have you tried "Quadratic Gauss sums"

Comment: @Somos Interesting you should mention that since [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3258069/4781) which mentions "gauss sums" led to a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4600807/) which then led to this present question since an integer relations algorithm couldn't find a simple sine-tangent equation for prime $p=8m+1.$

Comment: You get the quadratic Gauss sum, when $a_k$ range over the quadratic residues modulo $p$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Originally, I was curious about the integers $a_k$ based on the answers of this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3257939) but I also need them for my [new post on tangent products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4604210). I use Mathematica's integer relations for smallish $p$ and its PowerMod function for $50 < p < 5000$ (which I had to re-learn).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how it plays out when $p\equiv1\pmod8$. I think the assumption is needed for then we know that both $-1$ and $2$ are quadratic residues. With $p\equiv5\pmod 8$ there is probably a modification, but I'm down with a flu, so it will have to wait.

Let $Q$ stand for the set of (non-zero) quadratic residues modulo $p$. Let $D\subset Q$ be a set of representative of the quotient group $Q/\langle -1\rangle$. For example, we can choose $D$ to be the set of quadratic residues $\le (p-1)/2$. Let $N$ be the set of quadratic non-residues modulo $p$.

I will need the following fact (proof is not difficult, and very likely done elsewhere on the site):

**Fact.** If $j$ and $k$ range over $0<j,k\le(p-1)/2$, then the sum $j^2+k^2$ takes the values in $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$ with the following frequencies:
$$
j^2+k^2=\begin{cases}
0,\ \text{$(p-1)/2$ times},\\
q,\ \text{for every element $q\in Q$ exactly $(p-5)/4$ times},\\
n,\ \text{for every element $n\in N$ exactly $(p-1)/4$ times}.
\end{cases}
$$

Let us define
$$
S=\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}e^{2\pi j^2 i/p}=2\sum_{x\in Q}e^{2\pi x i/p}.
$$
The fact implies that in the sum $S^2+S$ every root of unity $e^{2\pi i\ell/p}$
appears exactly $(p-1)/4$ times except the root $1$ coming from $\ell=0$ that occurs $(p-1)/4$ times more often than the others.

By the well known result that the sum of all the roots of unity vanishes, this gives the equation
$$
S^2+S=(p-1)/4.\qquad(*)
$$
Applying the quadratic formula to $(*)$ implies that
$$
S=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt p}2.
$$
The famous Gauss's sign problem tells us that the plus sign always applies.

---

On with the sums of trig functions. Because $-1\in Q$, the roots of unity gives twice the cosines of $2\pi k/p$, $k\in D$. Next we use the trig identity
$$
\cos^2\alpha=\frac{1+\cos2\alpha}2.
$$
Because also $2\in Q$, we see that $2k$ ranges over $Q$ as $k$ does. Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k\in D}\cos^2\frac{2\pi k}p&=\sum_{k\in D}\frac12\left(1+\cos(2\pi 2k/p)\right)\\
&=\frac{p-1}8+\frac S4\\
&=\frac{p-2+\sqrt p}8.
\end{aligned}
$$
The sum of squares of sines can be handled similarly using the formula $\sin^2\alpha=(1-\cos2\alpha)/2$.

---

A Mathematica-example with $p=17$.

```
In[1]:=Sort[Table[Mod[k^2,17],{k,1,8}]]
Out[1]:={1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 13, 15, 16}
```

This implies that we can use $D=\{1,2,4,8\}$.

```
In[2]:=exp17={1,2,4,8};
In[3]:=N[Sum[Cos[2 Pi exp17[[ k]]/17]^2, {k, 1, 4}]]
Out[3]=2.39039
```

And the final check

```
In[4]:=N[(15 + Sqrt[17])/8]
Out[4]=2.39039
```

More later, if/when needed. I need to rest.

Comment: As said by several people earlier, this is a relatively straight forward application of quadratic Gauss sums. Ireland & Rosen surely cover this. Other texts as well.

Comment: Thanks for this! It is much better than my PowerMod version. By the way, I fixed Out[1] since you were using the "Sort" command, and the integers should have been sorted from smallest to largest. (I tried it on my version of Mathematica.)

Answer (score 3):

I found an algorithm to derive the correct set $H$ of $a_k$ for any prime $\ p=4m+1 \ $ (or its complement).

$H=\{ 1\}$.

For $k$ from $2$ to $2m$:

1. Compute $\alpha$ such that $\ \ k^2 \equiv \alpha \pmod{4m+1}\ \ $ and $\ \ 1\leqslant \alpha \leqslant 4m \ \ $
2. if $\ 1\leqslant \alpha \leqslant 2m \ $ then  $\ \beta =\alpha \ $ else $\ \beta = 4m+1-\alpha $
3. $H = H\cup \{\beta \}$

We can use "Quadratic Gauss sums" to show the result.

Comment: Do you use Mathematica? If you do, can you update your answer to include the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The ones that have all even or all odd quadratic residues relative to p, will do the trick.

The proof for this lies is polygon isomorphisms.  The numbers are invariant if taken to an e power (ie an even quadratic), but not an odd power.  So you end up with two numbers a, b whose sum would give p, and the difference is something in sqrt(p),