# On fundamental units and generalizing $\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}2\right)^{3/2} =\frac{\tan(t)\tan(3t)\tan(4t)}{\sqrt[4]{13}}$

Tags: trigonometry, algebraic-number-theory, radicals, closed-form

From this [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603836/), given $t = 2\pi/p$ for the appropriate prime $p=4m+1$, we find closed-forms only for $x,y$,

$$\begin{align}
x &= \sum_{k=1}^m \sin^2(a_k\, t) = \frac{p+\sqrt{p}}8 \quad\quad\\
y &= \sum_{k=1}^m \cos^2(a_k\, t) = \frac{(p-2)-\sqrt{p}}8 \quad\quad\\
z &= \sum_{k=1}^m \tan^2(a_k\, t) = \; ??\quad\quad
\end{align}$$

using the **same** finite sequence of integer $a_k.$

To find the closed-form of the tangent version is a bit trickier, though I know $z$ is also a root of a quadratic. But the tangent *product* using the **same** $a_k$ for certain $p=4m+1$ was slightly easier,

$$\begin{align}
\quad\quad\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\right)^{3/2} &=\frac{\tan(t)}{\sqrt[4]{5}}\\ 
\quad\quad\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}2\right)^{3/2} &=\frac{\tan(t)\tan(3t)\tan(4t)}{\sqrt[4]{13}}\\
\quad\quad\left(\frac{5+\sqrt{29}}2\right)^{3/2} &=\frac{\tan(t)\tan(4t)\tan(5t)\tan(6t)\tan(7t)\tan(9t)\tan(13t)}{\sqrt[4]{29}}\\
\end{align}$$

and so on for other primes.

**Question**: Given prime $\color{blue}{p=n^2+4}=4m+1,$ with $t = 2\pi/p.$ From the [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603836/), define the finite set of integer $a_k$ that satisfies,

$$x = \sum_{k=1}^m \sin^2(a_k\, t) = \frac{p+\sqrt{p}}8\quad\quad$$

Using the very same $a_k$, is it true that,

$$\quad w = \frac1{\sqrt[4]{p}}\,\prod_{k=1}^m \tan(a_k\, t)  = \left(\frac{\color{blue}n+\sqrt{p}}2\right)^{3/2} = \big(U_p\big)^{3/2}$$

where $U_p$ is a [*fundamental unit*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalUnit.html)?

Comment: It is hard to extract the definition of $a_k=a_k(t)$ (and the range of $k$) from the linked previous post. If it is a simple description (like quadratic residues modulo $p$, so there are $(p-1)/2$ of them) please insert it. Also, just to be sure, the long introduction regarding sums of $\sin^2$-values, then of $\cos^2$-values, shows just a far similarity to the stated question, and is in fact not really part of the question (and not anyhow useful for a proof - even in the mentioned cases)?! To get more related context, is there a proof (avoiding Mathematica & CO.) of any tangent product above?

Comment: @dan_fulea I've edited the post to make it more concise. Also, I revised the end question to make the definition of the $a_k$ clearer. And since we are dealing with primes $p=4m+1$, then the number of $a_k$ is just $m$. Those values of the tangent products $w$ were computer-aided, hence the question. Thanks for the suggestions.