# How to find the value of $4\cos(\frac{\pi}{26})+\tan(\frac{2\pi}{13})$

Tags: trigonometry

I have found in wolfram alpha that $\displaystyle 4\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{26}\right)+\tan\left(\frac{2\pi}{13}\right)=\sqrt{13+2\sqrt{13}}$.

How to prove this identity ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is old problem can see: [How prove this $\tan{\frac{2\pi}{13}}+4\sin{\frac{6\pi}{13}}=\sqrt{13+2\sqrt{13}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578286/how-prove-this-tan-frac2-pi134-sin-frac6-pi13-sqrt132-sqrt13?rq=1)

show that: The follow nice trigonometry

> $$\tan{\dfrac{2\pi}{13}}+4\sin{\dfrac{6\pi}{13}}=\sqrt{13+2\sqrt{13}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well you can look here

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi13.html

there something is explained...