# Proving $\sin\frac{\pi}{13}+\sin\frac{3\pi}{13}+\sin\frac{4\pi}{13}=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{13+3\sqrt{13}}2}$

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

> Prove that $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{13}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{13}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{13}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{13+3\sqrt{13}}{2}}$$

**My Attempt**

Let $$x = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{13+3\sqrt{13}}{2}} \implies 16x^4-52x^2+13=0$$
And through some donkey work we can calculate the chebyshev polynomial for $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{13}\right),\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{13}\right),\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{13}\right)$ which will all be the same as $\sin(n\pi)=0,\text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{I}  $, so
$$P(x) = 4096x^{12}-13312x^{10}+16640x^8-9984x^6+2912x^4-364x^2+13$$
where $x = \sin\left(\frac{2i\pi}{13}\right), \text{ from } 1 \le i \le 12 \text{ where } i \in \mathbb{I}$, are the roots of $P(x)$.

Now I am not getting how to connect these two into a possible solution and even it is possible (probably is), its still a pretty donkey method as you need to find the $13^{th}$ chebyshev polynomial, so if possible maybe give some another method of approach to this question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381294/how-to-prove-an-identity-trigonometry-angles-pi-13 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1590338/78967

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with $ \; w = \cos \frac{2 \pi}{13}  + i \sin \frac{2 \pi}{13} \; \; \; $  in mind, let
$$ x = -i \left( w - w^{25} +  w^3 - w^{23} +  w^9 - w^{17} \right)  $$

we may calculate polynomials in $x.$   We may then apply the relation $w^{26 }  = 1  $ repeatedly and   express the outcome as  sums of $w^{25}, w^{24}, ..., w^2, w,1 $

I get
$$ x^4 - 13 x^2 + 13 = w^{24} + w^{22} + \cdots w^4 + w^2 + 1 $$

with *no odd exponents*  and all the coefficients $1$

Multiply by the (nonzero)  $w^2 - 1 $  to get $ x^4 - 13 x^2 + 13 $

The original ideas were due to Gauss, see [Cox chapter](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/%7Ejagy/cox_galois_Gaussian_periods.pdf)

Many examples were worked out by Reuschle;
This comes from page 529: [Reuschle 1875](https://archive.org/details/tafelncomplexer00unkngoog/page/528/mode/2up)

[image]

Comment: what exactly did you do go from step 1 to step 2 ? Sorry I am not getting it...

Comment: What do you mean by steps 1 and 2?

Comment: Step (1)    $x=−i(w−w^{25}+w^3−w^{23}+w^9−w^{17})$


Step (2)    $x^4−13x^2+13=w^{24}+w^{22}+⋯w^4+w^2+1$

Comment: the other dude @robjohn did the transition by some matrix thingy which I only half understood because I don't know matrices and determinants but how did you do the transition

Comment: @sparrow_2764   multiply out $x^4$   and $x^2.$  The largest  exponent comes from the $\left(w^{25} \right)^4$   giving exponent 100.

Comment: oh ok I finally get it so you just brute force calculate $x^{4}$ and $x^2$ and then the relation will be easy to see (probably)... Anyways thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$
s=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{13}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{13}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{13}\right)\tag1
$$
If $\alpha=e^{\pi i/13}$, then
$$
\alpha^{13}+1=0\tag2
$$
and
$$
2is=\underbrace{\alpha+\overbrace{\quad\alpha^{12}\quad}^{-\alpha^{-1}}}_{2i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{13}\right)}+\underbrace{\alpha^3+\overbrace{\quad\alpha^{10}\quad}^{-\alpha^{-3}}}_{2i\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{13}\right)}+\underbrace{\alpha^4+\overbrace{\quad\alpha^9\quad}^{-\alpha^{-4}}}_{2i\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{13}\right)}\tag3
$$
Using the approach in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3851456), we get that the minimal polynomial of $x=2is$ is
$$
x^5+13x^4+13x=0\tag4
$$
Since we don't want $s=0$, we have
$$
x^4+13x^2+13=0\tag5
$$
which has roots
$$
x\in\left\{\pm i\sqrt{\frac{13\pm3\sqrt{13}}2}\right\}\tag6
$$
Since $\frac2\pi\theta\le\sin(\theta)\le\theta$ for $0\le\theta\le\frac\pi2$, we have $\frac{16}{13}\lt s\lt\frac{8\pi}{13}$. Therefore, we must have
$$
s=\sqrt{\frac{13+3\sqrt{13}}8}\tag7
$$

Comment: same thing here I am not getting it how you are going from step (3) to (4)... and yes I read your other answer but it is beyond my current knowledge ... I mean what is a "minimal polynomial"

Comment: Look at the linked answer. Using the relation $\alpha^{13}+1=0$, we get a basis of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$: $b=\begin{bmatrix}1&\alpha&\cdots&\alpha^{12}\end{bmatrix}^T$. Then we find the matrix, $M$, defining the action of $x=\alpha+\alpha^3+\alpha^4+\alpha^9+\alpha^{10}+\alpha^{12}$ on that basis; that is, $xb=Mb$. The characteristic polynomial of $M$ is $-\lambda(\lambda^4+13\lambda^2+13)^3$. The computational difficulty is that the matrix is $13\times13$, which means the degree of the characteristic polynomial is $13$.