# If $\sin(\pi/13)\sin(3\pi/13)\sin(4\pi/13)={a\over b}\sqrt{\frac{k-3\sqrt k}{2}}$, find $\frac{5a+b}{k}$.

Tags: analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, roots-of-unity

> If $\sin(\pi/13)\sin(3\pi/13)\sin(4\pi/13)={a\over b}\sqrt{\frac{k-3\sqrt k}{2}}$, find $\frac{5a+b}{k}$.

Let $s=\sin(\pi/13)\sin(3\pi/13)\sin(4\pi/13)$ and $x=\sqrt k$. Then the above equation becomes

$$\frac{x(x-3)}{2}=\frac{s^2b^2}{a^2}\text{ i.e. }x^2-3x-\frac{2s^2b^2}{a^2}=0$$

Therefore $\displaystyle{x=\frac{3|a|\pm \sqrt{9a^2+8s^2b^2}}{2|a|}}$

I have to find the $s$. There is a [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4647658/proving-sin-frac-pi13-sin-frac3-pi13-sin-frac4-pi13-frac12-sqrt) here which evaluates $\sin(\pi/13)+\sin(3\pi/13)+\sin(4\pi/13)$.

So if I assume $\alpha=e^{i\pi/13}$. We get $s=\frac{(\alpha+\alpha^{12})(\alpha^3+\alpha^{10})(\alpha^4+\alpha^9)}{-8i}$.

I am not having any idea to proceed further. Can anyone help me with an idea to deal with this problem? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Since the lhs $s$ is known but $a,b,k$ are unknown, imo the question of the title makes no sense.

Comment: @AnneBauval. This problem makes sense

Comment: Yeah, it looks like an Olympiad question where you represent something in a given form, and then find something, because all questions have positive integers as answers.

Comment: Are you supposed to assume that $a,b,k$ are all integers?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici ? If only ${a\over b}\sqrt{\frac{k-3\sqrt k}{2}}$ is known, this gives no information about $\frac{5a+b}{k}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval. The lhs is known

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Precisely, and only it. Whence my comment.

Comment: @Anne, yes. So, maybe we're meant to assume $a/b$ is in lowest terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [Newton-Girard formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Newton-GirardFormulas.html)
$$\prod_{n=1}^6  \sin \left(\frac{n\pi  }{13}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{64}$$
$$\frac{64}{\sqrt{13}}\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{13}\right) \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi
   }{13}\right) \sin \left(\frac{4 \pi }{13}\right)=\csc \left(\frac{2 \pi }{13}\right) \sec \left(\frac{\pi
   }{26}\right) \sec \left(\frac{3 \pi }{26}\right)$$ and the rhs is "just"
$$4 \sqrt{2-\frac{6}{\sqrt{13}}}$$ which makes

$${a\over b}\sqrt{\frac{k-3\sqrt k}{2}}=\frac{1}{16} \sqrt{13 \left(2-\frac{6}{\sqrt{13}}\right)}=\frac{1}{256}\sqrt{26-6 \sqrt{13}}$$

Just finish !

Comment: How does this help to answer the (absurd without more constraints) question?

Comment: Even assuming that $a,b,k$ are integers and $a,b$ coprime, how can we prove the uniqueness of the solution?