# Finding the value of a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

Find the numerical value of $$\tan(3\pi/11)+4\sin(2\pi/11)$$ without actually calculating the values. How to start? Please help.

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi11.html

Comment: Try converting all of the trigonometric functions to functions involving pi/11 using multiple angle formulae

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner : There's not a word on how to obtain the result of (13)

Comment: I want to know the method...

Comment: this will be help https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=riddles_hard;action=display;num=1167686768

Comment: I want a simple trigonometry proof... These links don't help

Comment: @You-know-me, Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11246/how-to-prove-that-tan3-pi-11-4-sin2-pi-11-sqrt11,  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578286/how-prove-this-tan-frac2-pi134-sin-frac6-pi13-sqrt132-sqrt13

Comment: Yeah, it is related. But I want a simple trigonometry proof. And the one given is totally out of the box. I mean, there has got to be a normal proof starting from my LHS and ending at RHS.